# vuetify change input slot color

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[vuetify form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Qhy.png)

Hi I'm using vuetify form layout for login page but I want to change that primary color inside of scss file.
is there's any way that I can change that color?

Answer (score 0):

You can change all your colors in the `src/plugins/vuetify.js` file.

For example:

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '#3f51b5',
        secondary: '#b0bec5',
        accent: '#8c9eff',
        error: '#b71c1c',
      },
    },
  },
```

Documentation on themes is [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/).